# joining and querying two tables with condtion

Tags: mysql, database, laravel

Table 1 :

```
users(id, fname,lname)
```

Table 2:

```
messages(id, body,sender_id, receiver_id) ..
```

**note:-** sender_id and receiver_id reference id in table 1.

```
select *
from messages
where receiver_id = 3
```

gives me result by.

I do not want  the sender id as id but as fname and lame from users table

Comment: You are asking for an inner join if I didn't get it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
select m.id,m.body,u.fname,u.lname from messages m
inner join users u on u.id=m.sender_id
where m.receiver_id = 3
```

Comment: select messages.id,messages.body,users.fname,users.lname from messages 
inner join users  on users.id=message.sender_id
where messages.receiver_id = 3     works fine.. tnx

Comment: Although this code might solve the problem, a good answer should always contain an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using [inner join](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-inner-join.aspx), you can use below query, here am making sender alias for users for more clarity

```
    select m.id, m.body, m.receiver_id, sender.fname, sender.lname
    from messages m
    inner join users sender on sender.id=m.sender_id
    where m.receiver_id = 3
```